# Customize search bar size in TwentyTwentyOne (Wordpress)

Tags: wordpress, header, searchbar

I placed the search bar in the header by adding the string in child Theme:

```
get_search_form ();
```

I wish the bar was shorter and aligned to the right.
I tried unsuccessfully to add the following to the stylesheet:

```
.search-form {
    max-width: 400px;
}

.search-form > label {
    width: 50%;
```

It does not work.
Can someone help me?

P.S. The page is this: https://www.carifiglimiei.com/

Answer (score 0):

'search-form' css class is not present in your website page.
Also

```
get_search_form ();
```

returns different structure than your current page html. I guess your search form is generated by any plugin.
Or feel free to share the search form code.

I used this function and found [this code structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f0lNI.png) (manually added a wrapper class: search-form-wrapper)

Answer (score 0):

As someone said above. Your search form is generated by some plugin and has no class `search-form`. From what I can see you should use class `gsc-search-box` as for editing in CSS. I tried to use this class and It worked. Hope I helped you :)